# Python how to escape option paraameters for pgrep in cli

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I am trying to prepare a command to find out if my `rsync` process is running using the `ps` command, when I run the script, the `pgrep` is throwing an error as invalid option, I want to know about how to escape the command in the below variable `self.getSrcCount`.

```
for n in range(0, len(self.chkMntPoints)):
    self.chkMntPoints[n]  = self.chkMntPoints[n].replace('\/','/')
    self.getSrcCount      = 'ps aux | pgrep'+' '+'rsync'+' '+'-avz'+' '+'--progress'+' '+self.chkMntPoints[n]
    print self.getSrcCount
    self.srcWord          = subprocess.Popen(self.getSrcCount, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    self.srcWc            = self.srcWord.communicate()[0].strip()
    print self.srcWc
    print len(self.srcWc)
    return len(self.srcWc)


Below is my output after the code execution:

pgrep: invalid option -- a
Usage: pgrep [-flvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
        [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]

0
pgrep: invalid option -- a
Usage: pgrep [-flvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
        [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]

0
```

Comment: What is your command supposed to be doing? you seem to be mixing prgep with rsync which would not work from bash either

Comment: I am just trying to find the length of output from the ps command. If the length is 0 then i will conclude the migration is completed or else i will display the message that the migration is still running.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative solution to simplify things. You can use `psutil` library to retrieve information on running processes: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil. It's easy to iterate through all running processes and check the name and startup parameters:

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print proc.name(), proc.cmdline()
```

Docs: https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/

Comment: yes, but the server doesn't have psutil module available.

Comment: If you are allowed to install it, you can do it with pip: pip install psutil